# Why is an orthogonal transformation invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

I am confused as to why an orthogonal transformation is necessarily invertible. I have defined an orthogonal transformation as a transformation $T:V\to V$ where $V$ is a vector space and $T$ has the property that $\langle T(x),T(y)\rangle=\langle x,y\rangle$ for all $x,y\in V$, and $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is an arbitrary inner product. Any advice on how to prove this, or a general explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need $V$ to be finite-dimensional. Start by showing that if $T(x) = 0$, then $x = 0$.

Comment: How is this? Let $T:V\to V$ be an orthogonal transformation. Then, for all $x,y\in V$, $\langle T(x),T(y)\rangle=\langle x,y\rangle$. Let $T(x)=0$. Then $\langle T(x),T(y)\rangle=\langle 0,T(y)\rangle=\langle0\cdot 0,T(y)\rangle=0\langle 0,T(y)\rangle=0\langle x,y\rangle=\langle 0,y\rangle$. Then, $\ker(T)=\{0\}$, so $T$ is one-to-one. Because $T$ is a linear operator and one-to-one, it must also be onto. Therefore, $T$ is invertible.

Comment: The sequence of equalities you really need to write down is just $\langle T(x), T(y) \rangle = \langle x, y \rangle = \langle 0, T(y) \rangle = 0$. This implies (for example by setting $y = x$) that $x = 0$, so $T$ is one-to-one. Next you need the finite-dimensionality of $V$ to conclude that $T$ is invertible.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

For any vector $v\neq0$ the distance from o is *positive*. If An orthogonal transformation were singular then for a $v\neq0$ in it's kernel, $T(v)$ being zero would be at zero distance from the zero vector, contradicting the fact that it has to preserve the distance.

Comment: Or just in one line: $Tx=0\;\Longrightarrow\;\|x\|^2 = \langle x,x\rangle = \langle Tx,Tx\rangle = 0$, hence $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

In the finite dimensional case $T $ can be represented by a square matrix $M $ whose columns are orthonormal.  Thus the columns are linearly independent and $M $  has full rank $n =dimV$.  Then necessarily  $detM\not=0$.  Hence  $M $ is invertible, and so is $T $...

Comment: It is completely unnecessary to use matrices here, and even when using matrices it's unnecessary to use the determinant.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan sure.   It was just off the top of my head. ..  I have probably begged the question in a place or two...

Comment: @QiaochuYuan As you know, there are literally dozens of equivalent conditions for a transformation to be invertible. Without more input from the OP, it's not clear that one description would be more illuminating than any other.

Comment: Yes, but most of them are irrelevant to this problem. Why use the determinant to show that if a square matrix has linearly independent columns then it's invertible?