# How to prove that a general orthogonal transformation has an inverse

Tags: linear-algebra

I see in [previous question on this subject](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2517645/why-is-an-orthogonal-transformation-invertible)
that an orthogonal transformation is 1-1. But how to show that it is onto? I see you need finite dimensionality. I would rather not resort to matrices for this.

Comment: In finite dimensions, into $\iff$ onto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if $T:V\to V$ is a 1-1 linear transformation and $V$ is a vector space of finite dimension then $T$ is also onto. It follows from the formula $dim(V)=dim(Ker(T))+dim(Im(T))$. If $T$ is 1-1 then $dim(Ker(T))=0$ and hence we get $dim(Im(T))=dim(V)$. Because we also know that $Im(T) \subset V$ and $V$ has finite dimension then we get $Im(T)=V$ and $T$ is onto.